# SQL Syntax Error with CREATE TABLE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I get a SQL Sytax Error when I try to execute this code:

```
CREATE TABLE ? (
ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`UUID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);
```

I use a PreparedStatement to replace the ? with a String

The Error Message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an errorin your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serverversion for the right syntax to use near ''95f7ed55-ab3d-46f9-bffe-72bf5780a1ec' (ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIM' at line 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits. ` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: It looks like you're using a single-quote to specifying the table name `'`.  Try using a backtick instead and see if this resolves it.

Comment: Can you please put your whole code, creating DDL using dyanmic sql?

Comment: You cannot use parameters for object names like a table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put table name into backticks, it contains `-` which has to be escaped.

You used single quotes (`'`), which are bad in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The sign (-) character is not allowed when not using quotes.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever
>   you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in
>   a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)

This is executed now:

```
CREATE TABLE 95f7ed55-ab3d-46f9-bffe-72bf5780a1ec (
ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`UUID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);
```

But the identifier on the first line needs to be quoted:

```
CREATE TABLE `95f7ed55-ab3d-46f9-bffe-72bf5780a1ec` (
```

Maybe something like this will do the trick? (edit: added "IF NOT EXISTS" from Anil Kumar's answer)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `?` (
ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`UUID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following query syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
pls try this code.

        CREATE TABLE `table_name`(
       `ID` INT( 255 ) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
       `UUID` VARCHAR( 36 ) NOT NULL
        );
```

Note: `table_name` using this symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createTblDynamically;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createTblDynamically(tblName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @tableName = tblName;
    SET @q = CONCAT('
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' , @tableName, '` (
            ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`UUID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    ');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
```